# Cannot find a way to display an adjacency matrix

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have a question about face adjacency graphs. Suppose that I have an adjacency matrix

[image]

How can I plot something like this?? I tried and it looks too messy. What may be the resulting graphic?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've seen `AdjacencyGraph[]`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
myMatrix = {{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

AdjacencyGraph[myMatrix, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph from adjacency matrix]

For your data, a `CircularEmbedding` with your vertex labels might be more revealing:

```
AdjacencyGraph[CharacterRange["a", "h"], myMatrix,
               VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image: circular embedding of adjacency graph]

Comment: Like in the comment above ?

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer it was very useful. Now I'm totally new to this site, could you tell me what program did you use to get that graph and where can I get it?

Comment: Ummm.... Isaac.... I'm astounded.  This site is devoted entirely to the computer language *Mathematica* and I posted the explicit code necessary to create the figures I displayed.  "What program...?" *indeed*!